# How to get only positive values in a monte-carlo simulation?

Tags: r, montecarlo

Using the code below we get 10,000 random values normally distributed around the mean and the values can be positive and negative. I am dealing with a problem where negative values of simulation result makes no sense. How can I generate a normal distribution with only positive values? Or is there any other appropriate way to handle this?

```
runs <- 100000
sims <- rnorm(runs,mean=30,sd=30)
```

Comment: Increase the mean or reduce standard deviation or consider another distribution, this is a statistical issue, not a programming problem.

Comment: Try `runif()` with lower limit in zero

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the negatives you can do this after your code. This will give you a kind of truncated normal distribution if that's what you're after.

```r
sims <- sims[sims>0]
```

Comment: This great if you are only concerned with the code to get rid of negative values, but, doing this will cause your sample will not be completely random. You are truncating your sample.